# How to programmatically pin a UIImageView

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, autolayout

I read the documentation, but I just can't figure out what exactly is needed in my simple case.
The element is constantly jumping. I need just that.
I would be grateful for articles and so on. For a deeper understanding of this

[image]

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
    
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        
        view.addSubview(imageView)
       
        
        self.view = view
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant code please.

Comment: Look up Auto Layout and/or SwiftUI.

Comment: To understand this topic, I recommend: Auto Layout by Tutorials By Jayven Nhan & Libranner Santos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Apply constraint

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10),
    imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
    imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1)
])
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for auto layout constraints.
E.g. add to your code:

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// add desired constraints here.
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
...
```

You may want to set top, leading and trailing anchors, depending on the desired behavior.

Comment: This spoon-feeding does not help him. Looking at what he has posted, he is fundamentally missing almost everything needed as far as setting constraints programmatically goes. 

As @TamásSengel said, a simple "programmatic auto layout constraints swift" tutorial is what's needed.

Comment: I agree and I hope @egor-gorskikh will invest in self-education